# SOLVED How do you attach the case fan on the Raspberry Pi 5?

Tags: case, cooling, pi-5

I can see where I'm supposed to plug the fan cable but it's covered up and I'm scared to tug on it in case I break it. Is there some knack to opening it?

[image: close up of fan socket]

[image: picture of rp5 and case]

Comment: what are you pulling?

Comment: Pull the stopper out push the connector in. Job done.

Comment: @jsotola, it seems obvious now, but I originally thought that beige block was a single piece of plastic. I was trying to rip the whole thing off the board 

Answer (score 10):

Ah, I figured it out, I was pulling the wrong bit, you just need to pull the square off the top.

[image: pi5 with fan socket cap removed]

Comment: Good show - solved your own problem!  You should "Accept" your answer to let other users know this is a correct answer. Note that you may have to wait a day or two before accepting - also, you get no points for accepting your own answer  :(

Answer (score 0):

Too bad I damaged mine when trying to get the cover off.
My understanding is that the pi 5 requires a fan.
What’s the purpose of the cover if the pi requires a fan anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious that the receptacle has a cap, particularly with weak eyesight. I broke off the header trying to remove it.